# Removing punctuation and no-Ascii characters in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset where I am reading some tweets where I have to remove punctuation and non-ascii characters and convert the text in small alphabets. How can I achieve this in a dataframe is there a way I can use Spark-Sql.

```
scala> data.show

+-----+--------------------+
|   id|               tweet|
+-----+--------------------+

|31963|#studiolife #aisl...|
|31964| @user #white #su...|
|31965|safe ways to heal...|
|31966|is the hp and the...|
|31967|  3rd #bihday to ...|
|31968|choose to be   :)...|
|31969|something inside ...|
|31970|#finished#tattoo#...|
|31971| @user @user @use...|
```

Comment: pls shoe some expected output, small alphabet?

Comment: Like the first tweet-: "#studiolife #aisl" can be written as "studiolife aisl" or 
"@user #white #su" as "user white su"

Comment: ok that is then clear for all

Comment: yes it just needs to be clean, can you help?

Comment: @AekanshGupta, Added more generic way of Removing punctuation and no-Ascii characters. Please have a look.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this for a DF column single character replace of a string column:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
 regexp_replace(df.col,  "[\\?,\\.,\\$]", ".")) 
 ... 
 val res = df.withColumn("some_col_cleaned", regexp_replace(df("some_col"), "[\\_,\\*,\\$,\\#,\\@]", "")) 
 ...
```

with a string type for column, this:

```
val res = df.withColumn("cleansed", regexp_replace(df("tweet"), "[\\_,\\*,\\$,\\#,\\@,\\&]", ""))
```

works fine

Comment: scala> regexp_replace(df.tweet,  "[\\?,\\.,\\$]", ".");

<console>:29: error: value tweet is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

       regexp_replace(df.tweet,  "[\\?,\\.,\\$]", ".");

Comment: df(tweet) use ()

Comment: scala> regexp_replace(df(tweet),  "[\\?,\\.,\\$]", ".");
<console>:29: error: not found: value tweet

Comment: Value not found:tweet, is it because I am using spark 2.1?

Comment: I am reading my data with command:

val df =  spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").format("csv").load("test_tweets_anuFYb8.csv")

Comment: Works for me.  Not sure

Comment: Need to use appropriate col bame

Comment: Show the col names

Comment: You may well have an array

Comment: Show schema pls

Comment: scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- tweet: string (nullable = true)

Comment: odd to say the least

Comment: Added the line with name tweet to answer explicitly, otherwise I do not get it

Answer (score 2):

More generic way-
Replace a **`non-word`** character except **`space`** as below-

```scala
val df = Seq("#studiolife #aisl", "@user #white #su", "oh! yeah #123 #su.").toDF("tweet")
    df.withColumn("clean_tweet", regexp_replace($"tweet", "[\\W&&[^\\s+]]", ""))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------+---------------+
      * |tweet             |clean_tweet    |
      * +------------------+---------------+
      * |#studiolife #aisl |studiolife aisl|
      * |@user #white #su  |user white su  |
      * |oh! yeah #123 #su.|oh yeah 123 su |
      * +------------------+---------------+
      */
```